# $\theta$-Holder function and weak derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $f:[0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $\theta$-Holder function, $0<\theta <1$, which has a compact support, say, $[1,2]$.
Does the weak derivative exist? Probably not...So far, I can only see it is true for Lipschitz functions.

Comment: See [A Hölder continuous function which does not belong to any Sobolev space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38751/a-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function-which-does-not-belong-to-any-sobolev-space) on MO.